# jQuery: how to dynamically show "hidden" list items after the previous list item has been shown?

Tags: jquery

Each of the list items is "hidden" and each list can only be shown after the list item before it has been shown.

```
// HTML
<ul>
    <li id="list-1" class="list-item">
        <a href="#">List 1</a>
    </li>
    <li id="list-2" class="list-item">
        <a href="#">List 2</a>
    </li>
    <li id="list-3" class="list-item">
        <a href="#">List 3</a>
    </li>
</ul>



// CSS
ul li {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

ul li a {
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
}


// jQuery
$('#list-1').animate({
    top: '0'
}, 500, function() {
    $('#list-2').animate({
        top: '0'
    }, 500, function() {
        $('#list-3').animate({
            top: '0'    
        }, 500)
    })  
})
```

The jQuery code above works if there is always going to be 3 list items, but how can that code be modified to accomodate any number of list items?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `.list-item` class for the selector, and inside an `.each()`, use `.delay()` to delay the animation by the `index` value of the current iteration multiplied by `500` milliseconds.

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/EFGCM/

```
$('ul > li.list-item').each(function( i ) {
    $('a',this).delay( i * 500 ).animate({ top: '0'}, 500);
});
```

- http://api.jquery.com/each/
- http://api.jquery.com/delay/

The `.delay()` requires jQuery 1.4 or later.

---

**EDIT:** This would be a little more efficient.

http://jsfiddle.net/EFGCM/3/

```
$('ul > li.list-item > a').each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(i * 500).animate({ top: '0'}, 500);
});
```

Comment: Way more pretty than my implentation! nice.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do it with `display: none;`?

That way you can use the selector `$("ul li:hidden:first")` to select the next hidden li. Not tested, but shouldn't work. :)

Edit: to do the animation you can use the jquery function `slideToggle()` or `slideDown()` instead of just `show()`

Answer (score 0):

A recursive function may be what you are after. Something like this:

```
function animateCascade(element){
    var element = $(element);

    if (element.length==0) return; // no more elements

    element.animate(
        {top: '0'},
        500,
        function(){
            animateCascade(element.next('.list-tem')); // get the next LI
        }
    );
}
animateIt($('#list-1')); // start at the beginning LI
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution

```
function slide($li) {
    if ($li.length == 0) return;
    $li.slideDown(500, function() {
        slide( $li.next(".list-item") );
    });
}

slide( $("ul li:hidden:first") );
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/MXxkd/